# How to fix 'Wordpress redirection loop problem in wp-login.php page'?

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, login, wp-login-form

When I am going to the wp-login.php page of my wordpress website, the login form is not showing. Instead I can see its redirecting back infinitely to the same page. I am confused why suddenly this is happening. The url of the login page is http://weblabx.com/setu/wp-login.php

Comment: Works for me. Try a private browser window.

Comment: Yes, it's working in private browser and also working firefox. But the problem is still  happening in chrome normal browsing mode. Do you have any idea, why this is happening?

Comment: Your browser is caching it. This is only an issue for you and will be temporary.

Comment: @MazharulIslamSetu this is a plugin redirection, so you need to wait until the cache is clear. No ctrl+f5 works. while you can use other navigator or other PC. this is pain in the neck.